# Not able to configure multiple public keys for AWS sFTP Account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sftp

We are currently setting up AWS sFTP (Transfer Family) that is "Service managed" and we added Users, which all have 1 public key.

All good so far.

Now we want to have some Users configured with 2 public keys, so two connections can be stablished to the same account with 2 different private keys.

Is this possible with AWS sFTP?

Custom sFTP setups can have multiple public keys for one account.

Comment: This is not a [programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Yes its an IT-Question. Search for Certificate and tell me, which of the thousands of topics is coding.

Comment: Yes, and IT questions belong to [su]. – The sad fact, that there are indeed zillions of off-topic questions on SO, does not justify you posting yet another one.

Answer (score 0):

Caveat: I haven't personally tried this configuration, but the docs seem to indicate that it is possible to add keys for server-managed users:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/transfer/latest/userguide/service-managed-users.html#edit-user-ssh-key

> Under SSH public keys, you can add or delete an SSH (Secure Shell) public key.
>
> > To add a public key
> >
> > Choose Add SSH public key to add a new SSH public key to a user.